# Passing boolean props to component doesnt work

Tags: react-native, components, react-props

I have component Form.js:

```
....

function Form() {
    return (
        <View>
            <FormButton primary text="Login" />
            <FormButton primary={false} text="Register" />
        </View>
    );
}

export default Form;
```

and second component - FormButton.js

```
....

function FormButton(props) {
    let {
        primary,
    } = props


    return (
        <Text>Primary: {primary}</Text>
    );
}

export default FormButton;
```

IT DOESN'T WORK. WHY?

When I pass props primary like a string:
`<FormButton primary="abc" text="Login" />`
It works, but when I try send it like boolean:
`<FormButton primary text="Login" />` or
`<FormButton primary={true} text="Login" />` or
`<FormButton primary={false} text="Login" />`

Answer (score 1):

Because if you pass props `primary` as boolean, you need to convert it to string. Simple use `toString()`:

```js
function FormButton(props) {
    let {
        primary,
    } = props


    return (
        <Text>Primary: {primary.toString()}</Text>
    );
}

export default FormButton;
```